# twocolumn pageref off by one on last page of \tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, two-column

I am trying to have the both the current and last page of the frontmatter in the footer, without using any extra packages. `onecolumn` does this without problem , but `twocolumn` causes a pageref on the last ToC page to point to the page immediately following it, so the page numbers become for an odd page:

**i, *cleared*, 1, 2, 3, ...:**

> i / **ii**
>   *cleared*
>   1 / 7
>   2 / 7
>   3 / 7
>   ...

while with `onecolumn` it correcly yields

> i / **i**
>   *cleared*
>   1 / 7
>   2 / 7
>   3 / 7
>   ...

and in the case of an even page `twocolumn` prints the page of the following chapter:

**i, *ii*, 1, 2, 3, ...:**

> i / **1**
>   ii / **1**
>   1 / 15
>   2 / 15
>   3 / 15
>   ...

while with `onecolumn` it correcly yields

> i / **ii**
>   ii / **ii**
>   1 / 15
>   2 / 15
>   3 / 15
>   ...

What could be causing this?

```
\documentclass[ a5paper
                ,17pt
                ,twocolumn
                ]{memoir}

\makeoddfoot    {plain}{}{{\thepage} / {\thelastpage}}{}
\makeevenfoot   {plain}{}{{\thepage} / {\thelastpage}}{}

\makepagestyle  {toc}
\makeoddfoot    {toc}{}{{\thepage} / {\pageref{lasttocpage}}}{}
\makeevenfoot   {toc}{}{{\thepage} / {\pageref{lasttocpage}}}{}

\AtBeginDocument{
    \addtocontents{toc}{
        \protect\thispagestyle{toc}
        \protect\pagestyle{toc}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\pagestyle{toc}
\tableofcontents
\label{lasttocpage}
\pagestyle{toc}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Example} \chapter{Example} \chapter{Example} \chapter{Example}
% uncomment for even page ToC ending
%\chapter{Example} \chapter{Example} \chapter{Example} \chapter{Example}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand\cfttocafterlisthook{\label{lasttocpage}}`? To get it away from the extra stuff added inside `\tableofcontents`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
\renewcommand\cfttocafterlisthook{\label{lasttocpage}}
```

`memoir` has hooks inside the `\tableofcontens` macro, suft that you can get stuff close to the reading of the toc file.